# Hibernate - Postgresql properties access

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am not able to access the postgresql db properties, which are in small letters. I would like to access the properties using camelCase. Please suggest me the required configuration .

Answer (score -1):

for configure postgreSQL using JPA you can use this persistence.xml
For that you have to create one folder called "META-INF" in your project. and in that folder you have to store this file.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="give_some_name" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Or using hibernate.cfg.xml
(Here no need to create "META-INF folder")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you @Naros.